# Fail to bind InAppBillingService when using IabHelper

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, in-app

I'm currently developing a game and try to implement In-app billing V3 of Google Play. I had followed the In-app sample and used `IabHelper`. However, when running the app in device, something goes wrong. I found that after `mHelper.startSetup`, neither `onServiceDisconnected` nor `onServiceConnected` was called. So I printed the result of `mContext.bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);` in the IabHelper Class. The result is `false`.

Here is my code:

```
private IabHelper mHelper;

// MainActivity onCreate
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    // ...
    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
    mHelper.enableDebugLogging(true);
    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                return;
            }

            if (mHelper == null) return;
        }
    });
}
```

And in the method `startSetup` of IabHelper Class:

```
public void startSetup(final OnIabSetupFinishedListener listener) {
        // ...
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
        serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
        if (!mContext.getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(serviceIntent, 0).isEmpty()) {
            // service available to handle that Intent
            boolean bRes = mContext.bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            // ### I printed the result here it was false
            Log.i("IAB", "IAB Service Result = " + bRes); 
        }
        else {
            // no service available to handle that Intent
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onIabSetupFinished(
                        new IabResult(BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE,
                        "Billing service unavailable on device."));
            }
        }
}
```

I don't know the problem. I have done:

- add permission: com.android.vending.BILLING
- copy the .aidl file from sample to /src/com/android/vending/billing
- my android target set to android-22

Any ideas what's wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I solved it by uploading the latest version of my game to developer console and debug the latest apk. The problem is gone. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Copy all the class from util folder from the Project **"Trivial"**
or you can copy whole **Util** package into your project. And then give a try.

Comment: yes, I had done this job before. I copied util folder from "Trival" project to mine, and just renamed the package name.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and found that

1. The app version debugged must be the same as the version released in developer console.
2. Play service needs to be available, some phones may actually kill the service after a screen lock, start play store, then redo the binding worked.
3. Using IabHelper out of box may trigger problems like service disconnect not handled, re-initialize fail, I had to modify it a bit.